# C# Linq merge two dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, merge, functional-programming

How to make the following method more functional-linq-style?

```
    public static Dictionary<T, T> MergeDict<T, T>(Dictionary<T, T> a, Dictionary<T, T> b)
    {
        var e = new Dictionary<T, T>();

        a.Concat(b).ToList().ForEach(pair =>
        {
            e[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
        });

        return e;
    }
```

Comment: What behavior do you intend if there is a key collision between the two dictionaries?

Comment: @ericj.: the value from b is used

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To continue your duplicate discarding ways, just group up and take a winning item in the group (such as the Last one).

```
first.Concat(second)
  .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Last());
```

Comment: This will actually have the opposite behavior - Values from "first" will be kept, where the OP will always get values from "second" (ie: `g.Last()` or reverse concat)

Comment: @ReedCopsey included by edit, thanks.

Comment: @davidb I think this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

You could use [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) directly:

```
public static Dictionary<T, T> MergeDict<T, T>(Dictionary<T, T> a, Dictionary<T, T> b)
{
     return a.Concat(b).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Be aware that this will raise an exception in the case of duplicate keys.

If you need to handle duplicate keys, you'll need to decide how you want this to be handled.  For example, this will remove duplicates from "b":

```
public static Dictionary<T, T> MergeDict<T, T>(Dictionary<T, T> a, Dictionary<T, T> b)
{
     return a.Concat(b.Where(kvp => !a.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

To get the same behavior as the original, you could go the other way (keeps KeyValuePair values from "b"):

```
public static Dictionary<T, T> MergeDict<T, T>(Dictionary<T, T> a, Dictionary<T, T> b)
{
     return b.Concat(a.Where(kvp => !b.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: Behaves differently towards duplicates. This version throws.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes - I edited to show how to avoid that...

Comment: @reedcopsey looks good, now I wonder what would be the most efficient solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this.

```
public static IDictionary<T, U> Merge<T, U>(this IDictionary<T, U> first, IDictionary<T, U> second)
{
    return first.Concat(second).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```